# Interpolate sin function between trough and peak point

Tags: trigonometry

Given two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ how would I find $sin$ expression in terms of $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that $(a,b)$ is in the first *trough* and $(c,d)$ is the first *peak*:

[image]

I have got as far as:

$$\sin\left(x-a-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+b+1$$

Where $(a,b)$ is in the first *trough* but I have been unsuccessful in incorporating $c$ and $d$. Where would I add $c$ and $d$ to make $(c,d)$ the first peak.

[Desmos Link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r1barlgocd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the period must be $2(c-a)$

The amplitude is $\frac {d-b}2$

The sinusiodal axis is at $y =  \frac {d+b}2$

So the equation must be ,,,

$$f(x) =  \frac {d+b}2 + \frac {d-b}2 \sin \bigg( \frac \pi{c-a} (x - h) \bigg)$$

where $h$ is the phase shift that can be determined by demanding that $f(a) = b$ or more simply, by demanding that at $x=a$ the function is at minimum so the argument of the sin function must be $-\frac \pi 2$

So $$ \frac{a-h}{a-c} = \frac 12 \implies h =  \frac {a+c}2   $$

Comment: Isn't the period $2(c-a)$? Another way to get $h$ is to observe that the function is midway between trough and peak (and rising) at $x = \frac12(a+c)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my first line